# What does this number represent?

Tags: warmachine

I've been away from Warmachine for a while and it looks like things have been significantly revised (RIP mage hunters VS warcasters). I was looking around in the new War Room v2 app and noticed a  number in the top right with the other abilities and stats that I can't find the purpose of. For Kaelyssa here, that value is 30. What is it?

[image: Kaelyssa's warcaster card with the number 30 in the top right corner circled]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the base size of the model. In Kaelyssa's case, and all other small base models, it's 30mm.

Here's a reference from PPS_Jackson on Reddit where he answers this very question:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Warmachine/comments/6afm9k/comment/dhfgmxg

> That indicates the models base size which is a new addition given how dragoons are now shown as two separate cards.